# Image in flex box showing different sizes between mobile device chrome and desktop chrome+device mode

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[codenpen](https://codepen.io/LOPOPO1111/pen/Yzwepgd)

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
}

.flex {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <img src="https://www.w3.org/Icons/SVG/svg-logo.svg">

</div>
```

I have built a flex box containing only one flex-item which is an image element.
The image element size is 150px x 150px when using Desktop Chrome and Desktop Chrome device mode(device: ipad).
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgKQo.png)

However, when I view the website on my Ipad, the image size is larger and its not 150px x 150px.
[screenshot of ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiGeB.png)

p.s: I gave the body a height of 150px and a border for better visualization of image height

My questions are:

1. How does this problem occur?
2. Why I can't see this problem on Desktop Chrome Device Mode? Does this mean I can't rely on Chrome Device Mode to check my website's mobile
   compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly set the size of the svg you should be good

eg, https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/JjGpyzR

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex">
   <img class="icon" src="https://www.w3.org/Icons/SVG/svg-logo.svg"> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
img.icon{
  height:150px;
}
```

> Why I can't see this problem on Desktop Chrome Device Mode? Does this mean I can't rely on Chrome Device Mode to check my website's mobile compatibility?

Previews are usually good, but there are exceptions. Another case where previews may not be accurate is when you forget to include a viewport meta tag

SVG sizing and behaviour is also a bit different than what you can expect with JPEG / PNG images, here's one link that might be helpful
https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

body > div.flex > img is your DOM tree.

heights:
body: 150px - css
div.flex:? - height not set
img:? - svg is scalable vector graphics so height isn't set either.

How the height is set eventually depends on standards, version, vendors etc':
In some versions the dimension comes from any ancestors up the dom tree,  others, from the direct parent only with fallback to view port.

My suggestion : just set the img element height, the rest will follow bottom up.